# Nit-picky question on the *about me* section

Tags: support, status-bydesign, profile-page

Whenever you view  a user's profile page who hasn't written anything in the *about me* section, you see this:

> Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about them.

Shouldn't it say: "about him/her"?

(Sorry for the pettiness-level of this question.)

N.B. I am not a native English speaker. However I am quite convinced that there is an error.

Comment: Singular "they". If you don't know the sex of who you're talking about, you can use a singular they to avoid the awkward he/she/it list.

Comment: For more info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they

Comment: It should be "...about themself", though.

Comment: @DanielFischer Not in a million years would I have guessed that. Still glad I asked though. It was eating at me for a while now.

Comment: I asked the same on English.SE: [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/240948/stack-exchange-profile-this-user-prefers-to-keep-an-air-of-mystery-about-them)

Comment: @NormalHuman Not if they prefer to keep an air of mystery about them like I prefer to keep my Swiss army knife about me.

Comment: @DanielFischer Fair point. I don't think I ever tried hard enough to parse the meaning of the phrase.

Comment: This seems related: [Why is the blank profile sentence not grammatically correct?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261359/why-is-the-blank-profile-sentence-not-grammatically-correct) (on the main meta).

Comment: @Daniel: Et tu, Brute? Are you also one of the last MacGyver fans on the face of this earth?

Comment: @Asaf, heck no, I still like MacGyver even if I last watched it decades ago. (FWIW, I steadfastly refuse to accept "singular they/them".)

Comment: @J.M.: There's also a small comic book that was released a few years ago with a story line that looks a bit like a two-part episode of MacGyver. It's pretty fun!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The words "they", "them", "their" are also commonly used as singular  gender-neutral forms.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they

Thus, the "them" there is intentional and not in error.

Comment: But also note, from the wikipedia site, "... its use has been criticized since the late nineteenth century, and acceptance varies."

Comment: *acceptance varies* ... In other words: Don't use in on your English homework, but also don't criticize others (such as stackexchange) for using it.

Comment: Referring to an indefinite person like everybody or someone as "they" has been used since Shakespeare's time. However, it seems to me that referring to a specific definite person like the author of a book whose gender is unknown as "they" had been almost non-exsistent before the *PC* was fashionable in the 1980s. Instead "he" had been universally used as a gender-neutral pronoun.
An indefinite person like everybody is semantically plural as the following sentence shows: "*Everybody knows each other*". However, a specific definite person like the author of a book is strictly singular.

Comment: I am neither particularly well-placed nor interested to discuss the merits of the chosen formulation or even the general practice. The point of my answer merely was to state that the present usage is common  and not a clear and simple error as OP might have thought (and that they thought so  is not surprising to me as indeed I never learned that usage while being taught English as a foreign language for quite some time).